# getting the second element of a list in dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, min, key-value-store

i am trying to get key of the minimun of the second element of a list in a dict, i have search in stackoverflow but i don t get anything, the most near that i found was the next code:

```
import operator
polo={78:[100,1],12:[101,0]}#
print(min(polo.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0])#i want that the operator compare "1" of the first list and "0" of the second key of the dict and give me the key that have the min value between that values 
#expected output was 12 but give me 78
```

but the only thing that return my, it is the min of the first element of the list and not the second element that is the element that i need it

Comment: if you will put a negative point give a comment to improve pls

Comment: Where is your [mcve]? Posting code that doesn't solve your problem, but not giving code for your actual issue, is not helpful

Comment: `dict` are not sorted in python versions below `3.7`, be warned.

Comment: You're taking the min over the list, not the last element within the list. You'll need a lambda function `min(polo.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1])[0]`

Comment: perhaps `min(polo.keys())` ?

Comment: No @DeveshKumarSingh not what OP wants if IUC

Answer (score 0):

```
polo={78:[100,1],12:[101,0]}
print(sorted((v[1], k) for k, v in polo.items())[0][-1])
```

This prints:

```
12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
polo={78:[100,1],12:[101,0]}

def find(dict):
    secondElements = {}    
    for key, value in dict.items():
        secondElements[value[1]] = key
    return secondElements.get(min(secondElements))

print(find(polo));
```